# Undefined method 'attempt'. in laravel VERSION = '7.30.4'

Tags: laravel, guard

I'm using Laravel  7.30.4  I want to authenticate Admins  but I am experiencing this error,

```
Undefined method 'attempt'. I'm trying to make login with admin guard so i using in my 

LoginController
```

**Here is a login function in  my Logincontroller:**

```
    public function login(LoginRequest $request){

        $remember_me = $request->has('remember_me') ? true : false;

        if (auth()->guard('admin')->attempt(['email' => $request->input("email"), 'password' => $request->input("password")], $remember_me)) {
           
            return redirect() -> route('admin.dashboard');
        }
       
        return redirect()->back()->with(['error' => 'erreur']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show your config/auth.php? There is probably the „admin“ guard missing.

Comment: there is more to that error message, like what that method is being called upon ... not every 'guard' has an `attempt` method, only the Statefull guards by default do

Comment: @codedge  here is my auth.php  code :                                                                        
       '  'guards' => [
        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],
        'admin' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'admins',
        ],
        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],  '